# Serialization: Enforce Element Value Must Be Unique

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm writing a class in C# using .NET 4.5 and am trying to enforce a rule when a list of this class is deserialized that one of the fields must be unique across all of them. Essentially:

```
[Serializable]
public class Item
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

When I serialize or deserialize a list of this class, I want to validate that all of the ID's are unique among the given collection. Can I enforce this using any Xml... attributes? Or do I have to accept the Xml that is deserialized as valid and then process it code-side? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you take care of that _before_ serialization? Seems like mixing responsibilities.

Comment: Well I want it on both sides. If someone were to edit the Xml, I'd like it if the serializer could validate the Xml for that condition before it is read in.

Comment: Not a task for serialization. Read it in and validate/fix it.